# Usage of `stage_in` in compute function in Metal

Tags: ios, indexing, gpu, metal

I was reading `Metal Shading Language` specification of Apple and I wonder about `stage_in` parameter. The doc says that this identifier can be used in order to implement per-thread input.

> The stage_in attribute in a kernel function allows
>   you to decouple the data type used to declare the per-thread inputs in
>   the function from the actual data type used to store the per-thread
>   inputs.

Now, it's very typical situation for kernel shader which does some heavy calculation to have in arguments big containers of data. For instance, if you're implementing matrices multiplication via `Metal` shader, you will have to pass that data to GPU and fetch necessary pieces in each GPU thread in order to perform multiplication. And I noticed that one of the biggest bottle-necks in `Metal` shader is dynamic indexing of such arrays and sometimes it's very hard to avoid that.

So what I understood from the `Metal Shading Language` spec that this `stage_in` parameter solves that issue. That it allows somehow (well, not somehow, but with using `attributes` mechanic) to link only necessary piece of data to each GPU thread and I will not need to fetch data out of array with dynamic indexes because function will be linked to needed piece of data from the start.

I'm in the middle of figuring out of how to use `stage_in` with `kernel` shaders but now I'm getting second thoughts - are my assumptions correct about `stage_in`? Does it solve the problem with dynamic indexing?